# What day number in TABLEAU online

Tags: date, tableau-api

I want to extract DAY number from any dynamic date
is there a better way to do it?
I need to recieve an integer as a result

this does not work =

```
DAY(Today())
```

Answer (score 0):

added MAX to property and it sorted out